# Is there any other method to creating UI for android application rather than XML?

Tags: android

It seems to difficult to creating UI for android application using XML layout (:at least for me).is there any plug-ins or any other method by which I can create UI for Android application ??

Comment: If you are serious about Android development then you really should learn how to use the xml files. It may seem difficult at first but it will give you a much better sense of what you are doing and you will be able to achieve more with more flexibility for your apps.

Comment: @codeMagic,yeah i am also thinking of learning XmL rather than searching other tools to implement UI ;)

Comment: If you haven't already, look at the [Layout Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html). That is your best bet. As @Raghav Sood said in his answer, it becomes second nature once you get used to it. Start with a simple `LinearLayout` and some `Views`. Then learn how to use `RelativeLayout` (the best in most situations, IMHO) then you can get your hands in some other `Layouts`. Give it a try, look up posts on here and the Google, and post a specific question when you get stuck. Good luck!

Comment: thanks,I will try to learn XML from now as you said ..

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult at first but once you're used to it it is second nature. If you intend to take up Android development seriously, XML UIs is an essential skill and you should learn it well.

That said, the Eclipse setup for Android has a GUI layout maker as well, and there is [DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) as well.

You can also recreate about 95% of XML layouts using Java code if it suits you better.

Comment: "Raghav Sood" says that 95% of the stuff you can do with xml can also be done with java code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html which has GUI design tools. It's pretty easy, you can just drag and drop the widgets you like.

Comment: Note that these tools are usually no good for designing GUIs that scale well.

Comment: but i think its included by default in Eclipse when i installs android-sdk !!

Comment: Yes, Eclipse has a GUI which is fine to start but you don't want to rely on it too much. Once you learn how the `Layouts` work and code the xml yourself you will be much better off...so will your users :)